# Algorithm for Minimum Weight Maximal Independent Set

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Is there any algorithm for finding the minimum weight maximal independent set? Instead of finding all maximal independent sets and keeping the one with less weight, is there any easier method to do it?

Comment: Do you really mean "easier" or do you mean "more efficient"?  If you care about ease of implementation, the easiest algorithm to implement is to enumerate all subsets and check each one to see whether it is maximal, and keep the one with minimum weight.  However this is very inefficient.

Comment: See https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023/A:1008765214400.pdf.  It's NP-complete and hard to approximate within a constant factor, so there's (probably) no efficient method.